# How to declare mem_fn without auto?

Tags: c++

How to declare `m` without `auto` for later assignment?

I only see `mem_fn()` with `auto` [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn), [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321362/how-declare-a-c-mem-fnmember-function-in-function-declaration) and [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625665/mem-fn-to-function-of-member-object).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Class
{
public:
    void display() { std::cout << "display" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{    
    auto m = std::mem_fn(&Class::display);
    Class instance;
    m(instance);
}
```

<sub>[on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Td3behG83)</sub>

Because cppreference says I should use 2 arguments, I tried:

- `std::mem_fn<void(), Class>`
- `std::mem_fn<void, Class>`

Comment: This is the kind of situation that `auto` is meant for. Why would you NOT want to use it?

Comment: This is an obvious case of a XY problem. In no case should you need to specify an unspecified type. Either use `std::function` or a member pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read your cppreference link carefully, it says `/* unspecified */` for the return value. That means, each compiler vendor can implement it like they want. So `auto` is a very good choice.

You can use [CppInsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGlvc3RyZWFtPgojaW5jbHVkZSA8ZnVuY3Rpb25hbD4KCmNsYXNzIENsYXNzCnsKcHVibGljOgogICAgdm9pZCBkaXNwbGF5KCkgeyBzdGQ6OmNvdXQgPDwgImRpc3BsYXkiIDw8IHN0ZDo6ZW5kbDsgfQp9OwoKaW50IG1haW4oKQp7ICAgIAogICAgYXV0byBtID0gc3RkOjptZW1fZm4oJkNsYXNzOjpkaXNwbGF5KTsgLy8gSG93IHRvIGRlY2xhcmUgdGhpcyB3aXRob3V0IGF1dG8gZm9yIGxhdGVyIGFzc2lnbm1lbnQ/CiAgICBDbGFzcyBpbnN0YW5jZTsKICAgIG0oaW5zdGFuY2UpOwp9&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0) to figure out what it compiles to: `std::_Mem_fn<void (Class::*)()>`, which is an internal type. **Don't use this type.**

If you plug that back to Godbolt, it currently works on gcc 12.2, clang 14.0.0 and MSVC 19 (all with C++20). But since this is an implementation detail, it may not last long.

Conclusion: using `auto` here is perfect. You don't need to understand the details of each and every type there is. Sometimes, it just works.

It's like a small child using a swing: they can have fun on the swing without understanding gravity. So for you: you can just have fun using `mem_fn()` without understanding the internals of the type.

Comment: _"If you plug that back to godbolt, it works on gcc 12.2, clang 14.0.0 and MSVC 19"_ please don't. That type is an internal implementation detail. Using it is asking for all sorts of trouble. The fact that you need to say what compiler version it works on should be a screaming red flag (which by the way is also the wrong thing to look at, it should be the _library_ version).

Comment: @PasserBy: granted, it may not be obvious to everyone that `_Mem_fn` is an internal type that you shouldn't use. I clarified that. My intent for specifying the compiler versions was just that I tested it with those versions, not that I needed to specify that. I also clarified that.